# Django not sending email when attachment size is near to 1 mb Error message SMTPServerDisconnected

Tags: django, email, size, attachment

I am able to send email with django, in normal course. But when size of attachment is more than few hundred kb, it is showing error. i am not able find the exact cause.

i tried changing mysql my.conf max_allowed_packet=10M

SMTPServerDisconnected at /sendemail/forfinal
Server not connected
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://10.0.10.106/assetlist/sendemail/forfinal?doeinput=27-Mar-2021&dofentryinput=2021-04-02
Django Version: 3.1.6
Exception Type: SMTPServerDisconnected
Exception Value:
Server not connected
Exception Location: c:\python\lib\smtplib.py, line 357, in send
Python Executable:  C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Python Version: 3.7.9
.
.
.
.
During handling of the above exception ([WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host), another exception occurred:
.
.
.

Comment: What mail server are you using?

Comment: smtp.office365.com

Comment: message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject,body,"shiv.kumar@icai.in",["shiv.kumar@icai.in"])
    filename = doeinput+'.csv'
    message.attach(filename, csvfile.getvalue(), 'text/csv')
    message.send()